# Server errors with rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've changed my CMS and need to redirect some of the old URLs.

What I'd like to do is:

1. remove "blog/archives"
2. replace underscores with dashes
3. replace ".html" with a trailing slash

The old link:

```
http://example.com/blog/archives/the_post_title.html
```

The new link

```
http://example.com/the-post-title/
```

I have written, and it was working at one point, but I'm getting 500 errors now.

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]   #Replace "_" with "-" loop until one left
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2        #Replace the last underscore
RewriteRule ^(.*?).html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]     #Strip the ".html" and use the filename as the url, note this as "permanently moved" (301)
```

Any idea why I'm getting server errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing that with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !_
RewriteRule ^blog/archive/(.*).html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. This did resolve the 500 error, but now I'm getting a 404. If I manually make the changes to the URL I do get the new post, so it's not something with that. As for the first req, these old posts were from an old CMS that generated HTML files, so I've got these rules in a .htaccess file in the /blog/archives directory - thus when taking the URL back to root (/$1/) it takes care of this.

Comment: What URL do you get redirected to?

Comment: The URL isn't changing at all.

Comment: This is my whole .htaccess. `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !_
  RewriteRule ^(.*?).html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Is this htaccess in your document root?

Comment: No, it's in the /blog/archive directory.

Comment: Try moving them to the document root's .htaccess. The repeating `^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2` rule will break otherwise. Also note I updated the rules above.